# Promise in a preexisting method

Tags: javascript

Currently I have the following code:

```
  let getThemeId = getMainThemeId();
  getThemeId.then(id => {
    themeId = id;
    csi.evalScript("exportAIHtml()", function(result){
      alert(result);
    });//main()
  });
```

getTheme is a method that returns a value and then I'm able to run .then.
First part works correctly.
csi.evalScript is a method prebuilt into a module I'm using.  It returns a callback so I can use the result.  For code clarity I would like to use the result in another then.

I've attempted this:

```
  let getThemeId = getMainThemeId();
  getThemeId
  .then(id => {
    themeId = id;
    return csi.evalScript("exportAIHtml()", function(result){
      return (result);
    })
    .then(result => alert(result));
```

The alert there is appearing as undefined so obviously it's not waiting for it to finish executing.  Would this have to be wrapped in a new promise to get it to work as expected?  Shouldn't it just chain it and continue the then?

Comment: You can't return from a callback like that. Either wrap it in a `new Promise` yourself, or use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Comment: Yes, you'd use `new Promise(resolve => { csi.evalScript("exportAIHtml()", resolve); })`

Comment: Btw, don't use a global `themeId` variable that you assign to from inside an asynchronous callback.

Comment: Ok thanks or the tip @Bergi